# Should I use immutable collections in Scala.js

Tags: scala-collections, scala.js

As I understand it, in scala.js the `js.Array` is equivalent to `mutable.Seq`. If I convert it to immutable collections like `List` and `Vector`, would it impact performance significantly in the browser?

What's the rule-of-thumb / best-practice on using immutables in scala.js?

Answer (score 1):

It's not too terribly different from the situation on the JVM, really. The usual rule of thumb is that Immutable Is Good -- it tends to produce cleaner, easier-to-reason-about and more-maintainable code.

For inner loops (and especially for "builder" functions that take some data and *result* in an immutable structure) it's sometimes worth using mutable data types for performance, and sometimes you have no choice in the matter when you are interacting with the JS side of things. But I'd say that best practice is to default to immutable unless you have reason to believe that a function or type is performance-critical...